# How do I adjust the size of a Vimeo player size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, vimeo

I am using the Vimeo Developer API and I'm having difficulty adjusting the player size. Ideally I would like to scale the player down in size. If you visit crossborders.tv/client/frisbie and go to the Work section you can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have a solution to your problem, and if you don't get the help from here I would suggest you to use Video's own forum for your question:

[API Forum on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/forum%3aapi)